# rospy: Approximate sync

Tags: rospy, synchronization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there an approximate synchronisation in rospy? I can't found anything in the documentation. Only here http://www.ros.org/wiki/message_filters section 8.1 speaks about python but it seems as copy paste from section 5.1.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44542/rospy:-approximate-sync/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a version that was implemented in image_pipeline/camera_calibration here:

https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/image_pipeline/trunk/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/approxsync.py

I think there's a ticket to migrate it to rospy, but I don't know the status of that.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on 2012-09-25**:
Thanks, I will check that.

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2013-06-03**:
Link doesn't work anymore, but the code can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ros-perception/image_pipeline/blob/groovy-devel/camera_calibration/src/camera_calibration/approxsync.py)